# Angular Slickgrid | How to disable the row selection of checkboxSelector of selectableOverride dynamically

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

Want to disable the selected row items by updating the `gridOptions` after some button clicks.

```
initGridOptions() {
   this.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enablePagination: true,
      enableAutoResize: true,
      autoResize: {
        containerId: 'grid-wrapper',
        sidePadding: 5
      },
      alwaysShowVerticalScroll: false,
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      checkboxSelector: {
          hideInFilterHeaderRow: false,
          hideInColumnTitleRow: true,
      },
      rowSelectionOptions: {
          // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
          selectActiveRow: false
      }
   }
}

//prepareGrid() { ...... }

disableButtonClick() {
    this.gridObj.setOptions({
        checkboxSelector: {
            selectableOverride: (row: number, dataContext: any, grid: any) => {
               // validate each row and disable the selected rows
               return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slickgrid-changing-columns-issue-r6ndzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can toggle the checkbox column without removing it (maybe with `grid.setColumns()` but it's probably better to just use the `selectableOverride` callback. It will allow you to dynamically change its usability on the fly (see the [Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Row-Selection#disable-custom-rows-selections-via-selectableoverride)) and in your case just use your boolean flag to have the callback return true or false (the later will disable/remove all checkboxes)

```js
export class Example1 implements OnInit {
  prepareGrid() {
    this.gridOptions = {
      enableRowSelection: true,
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,
      checkboxSelector: {
        // you can override the logic for showing (or not) the expand icon
        // for example, display the expand icon only on every 2nd row
        selectableOverride: (row: number, dataContext: any, grid: any) => (dataContext.id % 2 === 1)
      },
      multiSelect: false,
      rowSelectionOptions: {
        // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
        selectActiveRow: true,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

As per the new comments and the stachblitz, you need to have only 1 common method and in that method you do different logic depending on what button is clicked outside. For example, if I take some code from your demo, let's use a new flag `showOnlyOddRows = false` and let say that when you click your external button it will turn that flag to `true` and as we can expect it will re-render the grid and only show the row selection on odd rows

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  showOnlyOddRows = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gridOptions = {
      checkboxSelector: {
        hideInFilterHeaderRow: true,
        hideInColumnTitleRow: false,
        selectableOverride: this.validateRowSelection.bind(this)
        // or
        // selectableOverride: (row: number, dataContext: any) => this.validateRowSelection(row, dataContext),
      },
      // ...
    };
  }

  validateRowSelection(row: number, dataContext: any, grid: any) {
    return this.showOnlyOddRows ? dataContext.id % 2 === 1 : true; // returning true means that we want to show the row selection
  }

  // change flag when external button is clicked and re-render grid with new row selection set
  disableOddRows() {
    this.showOnlyOddRows = true;
    this.gridObj.invalidate(); // this will re-execute the validateRowSelection method
  }
```

So again, do not change the override with `setOptions`, it will completely break the code, so don't do that. If you really need to change options of the plugin, you should use the plugin `setOptions` not the `grid.setOptions`. Something like `this.angularGrid.extensionService.getSlickgridAddonInstance(ExtensionName.checkboxSelector).setOptions({ /* ... */ })` or `this.angularGrid.extensionService.getSlickgridAddonInstance(ExtensionName.checkboxSelector).selectableOverride = newOverrideFn` ... but again I probably wouldn't do that, it's easier to just keep 1 method with different logic inside it (like `validateRowSelection` shown earlier)

Comment: `selectableOverride` works perfectly on first time grid load but I wanted to disable/remove the checkbox selector(only specific rows) on button click(after grid load).. I have tried updating the `setOptions()` but its not working..

Comment: you should still use the override, try calling `grid.invalidate()` after you change your flag, this should force a grid re-render and then force override to be re-executed

Comment: I tried invalidating the grid and render again but didn't work. I have created a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slickgrid-changing-columns-issue-r6ndzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts) project. Can you help ?

Comment: ahh no I see your mistake, it helps a lot with the stackblitz, so the problem that you were redefining a new method again with `setOptions` but don't do it will become out of sync. What I meant is that you declare 1 (only 1) common method and in that method you do different logic and then call invalidate, it does work after modifying it in your stackblitz (though it's hard to see since font-asesome icons aren't showing up). I will update my answer